# What affect does inheriting from Kivy Widget class have on the child?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

First, a heads up - I am not too familiar with OOP concepts, so this may just be some form of python functionality that I am not aware of.

In Kivy we can modify the behaviour and appearance of widgets by creating classes child to the widgets whose functions we want to alter, for instance:

```
class MyWidget(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint = None
        self.size = 200, 100
```

Then use `MyWidget:` or `<MyWidget>` to instantiate the widget in *kv*. This is good if I wish for my widgets to be parent to the root widget, but there are times when this is not wanted for instance when requiring a temporary `Popup`.

In which case I would just create a typical class which is instantiated when an event is triggered. Like so:

```
class Interface():
    def __init__(self):    
        btn = Button()
        btn.bind(on_press=self.some_callback)

        self.popup = Popup(content=btn)
        self.popup.open()   

    def some_callback(self, instance):
        print('woo')
```

And this, to all appearances, looks fine, but the widget events (`on_press` here) don't trigger callback functions??? The `bind()` function will call the callback on the event, since I will be notified if the callback function definition has incorrect syntax, but for some reason the contents of the callback are not executed - only when `Interface()` inherits from the `Widget()` class (`Interface(Widget): ...`).
From the [docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html):

> Widget interaction is built on top of events that occur. If a property changes, the widget can respond to the change in the ‘on_’ callback. If nothing changes, nothing will be done.

`btn` is the widget, it is instance of `Button()` which itself is a child of `Widget`, its method has no connection at all to what may be the parent class of `Interface` so why then is the callback only fully executed when `Widget` is the parent class of `Interface`? What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like `Widget` defines all the stuff needed to register/support the events... when not inheriting from it you don't get that functionality...

Comment: @JonClements yes but taking `btn` for example; the parameters are passed to the `bind()` method, all the functionality occurs within the `bind()` method of the `Button()` class. I don't see what affect `Widget` could possibly have on this process at all

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if Button inherits from Widget itself :) Which means you'll get Widgets functionality, specialised by stuff in Button, and then what you write on top.

Comment: @JonClements it does you are right, which is why I am confused! since this is the case, how could having the class in which `btn` is instantiated be child of `Widget` possibly do anything at all??

Comment: Umm... think I might have been misinterpreting your question... as you saying that `btn.bind(on_press=some_callback)` doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @JonClements that is correct. It does not work fully, as explained in the question, if `Interface()` does not inherit from `Widget`. I just tried again, and this is indeed the case. Remove `Widget` as the parent of `Interface()`, and suddenly the callback stops calling when the event is triggered..

Comment: Right... so that's expected? I'm not sure where Interface and your `btn` are related here?

Comment: @JonClements sorry `btn` is instantialised in the `Interface` class

Comment: Okay... and how are you using `Interface` with that `btn`... I'm even less sure what you've got now :)

Comment: @JonClements okay I've updated my question. Let me know if you need further details.

Comment: Where is `some_callback` ?

Comment: @JonClements I have not included the callback, as it is just a regular method - there is nothing special within it - it could just contain a print statement. I went and added it anyway**